# Как оптимизировать задачу по времени?

Tags: python, алгоритм

Есть код

```
n, m = map(int, input('').split())
grades = list(map(int, input().split()))


def calculate(m, grades):
    result = 0

    for i in range(m):
        if grades[i] != 0:
            result += grades[i]**2
            counter = 0
            for j in range(i + 1, m):
                if counter == grades[i]:
                    break
                if grades[j] != 0:
                    result += grades[j]
                    counter += 1
        return result


print(calculate(m, grades))
```

Как убрать в нем циклы, без потери функционала кода, так сказать.
Условие задачи
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Т.е. вы рассчитываете что кто-то прочитает ваш код, догадается что он делает (если ещё поверить что в нём нет ошибок) и напишет вам код лучше? А может всё-таки опишете русским языком что это этот код должен делать?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Добавил )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте дополнительный список, в который собирайте кумулятивные (накопленные) суммы ненулевых оценок. Например, для `gr = [1,0,2,0,0,3,0,4]` это будет `cs = [1,3,6,10]`.

Чтобы найти частичную сумму по ячейкам с `а` по `b` включительно, нужно вычесть `cs[b]-cs[a-1]`.

Списки обходить с конца, индекс в `cs` уменьшается, когда ненулевое значение в `gr`.

В принципе, исходный список можно сжать, удалив нули, но радикально это ничего не улучшит, т.к. решение и так получится линейным